# Is there any way to define back/forward button effects on a web page?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page where the content is delivered mostly though javascript. Hitting the back button would basically exit the page to wherever the user came from instead of showing the previous content. Is there a way to take manual control over what the back/forwards buttons do on a web page?

Comment: take a look at the answer linked above—it should be able to help you out!

Answer (score 2):

This is a classic AJAX problem - each page is loaded asynchronously with no new GET from the browser, thus no history.

Look into History API of HTML5 to programatically push page state into the browser history. Other than that you are out of luck.